# Is there a CRUD generator utility in Scala (any framework) like Scaffolding in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, scala, crud, scaffolding

See: [Is there a CRUD generator utility in Java(any framework) like Scaffolding in Rails?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/414583/is-there-a-crud-generator-utility-in-javaany-framework-like-scaffolding-in-rai)

I have the same question but regarding Scala. I know Play framework 1.x had generators, but 2.x removed them, is there any working CRUD / Scaffolding generator for any Scala based web framework?

Comment: No, was some talk on the play user group about this, nothing planned. Twitter Bootstrap + DAO implementation + RESTful routing is your best bet; i.e. roll your own.

Comment: @virtualeyes Thanks, I was worried it's the case. I was thinking tinkering with creating one for educational purposes, is there anything I should be aware of before I venture into this experiment? Anything to start off from?

Comment: Check the docs on integrating TB, pretty awesome, gives you a great headstart, CRUD with Play is fairly easy.

Comment: @virtualeyes Thanks, pardon my ignorance, what does TB stand for? couldn't find it in the docs: https://www.google.com/search?q=TB&sitesearch=playframework.org%2Fdocumentation%2F2.1-RC4

Comment: Twitter Bootstrap, or a terrible disease -- in this case, it's the former ;-)

Comment: @virtualeyes - If you're game to recap the solution as your own answer, I'll delete my answer. (See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/90263/unanswered-question-answered-in-comments for elaboration of why this is helpful.) Thanks!

Comment: @DreadPirateShawn I don't care, use it as your own ;-)

Answer (score 2):

I was searching for a scaffolding tool too (which popped your question) and found this: http://skinny-framework.org/documentation/scaffolding.html

I did **not** tried it yet but the doc looks like it's going to do the job:

`./skinny g model tweet userId:Long text:String user:Option[User]`

will create

```
package model

import skinny.orm._, feature._
import scalikejdbc._
import org.joda.time._

// If your model has +23 fields, switch this to normal class and mixin scalikejdbc.EntityEquality.
case class Tweet(
  id: Long,
  userId: Long,
  text: String,
  user: Option[User] = None,
  createdAt: DateTime,
  updatedAt: DateTime
)

object Tweet extends SkinnyCRUDMapper[Tweet] with TimestampsFeature[Tweet] {

  override lazy val defaultAlias = createAlias("t")

  lazy val userRef = belongsTo[User](User, (t, u) => t.copy(user = u))

  /*
   * If you're familiar with ScalikeJDBC/Skinny ORM, using #autoConstruct makes your mapper simpler.
   * (e.g.)
   * override def extract(rs: WrappedResultSet, rn: ResultName[Tweet]) = autoConstruct(rs, rn)
   *
   * Be aware of excluding associations like this:
   * (e.g.)
   * case class Member(id: Long, companyId: Long, company: Option[Company] = None)
   * object Member extends SkinnyCRUDMapper[Member] {
   *   override def extract(rs: WrappedResultSet, rn: ResultName[Member]) =
   *     autoConstruct(rs, rn, "company") // "company" will be skipped
   * }
   */
  override def extract(rs: WrappedResultSet, rn: ResultName[Tweet]): Tweet = new Tweet(
    id = rs.get(rn.id),
    userId = rs.get(rn.userId),
    text = rs.get(rn.text),
    createdAt = rs.get(rn.createdAt),
    updatedAt = rs.get(rn.updatedAt)
  )
}
```

hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

Copying the answer from the comments in order to remove this question from the "Unanswered" filter:

> No, was some talk on the play user group about this, nothing planned. Twitter Bootstrap + DAO implementation + RESTful routing is your best bet; i.e. roll your own.
>
> ...
>
> Check the docs on integrating TB [Twitter Bootstrap], pretty awesome, gives you a great headstart, CRUD with Play is fairly easy.

~ answer per [virtualeyes](https://stackoverflow.com/users/185840/virtualeyes)