# Generate simple JAVA CRUD classes from existing MySQL database

Tags: java, mysql, database, crud

What I have now is a simple relational database in MySQL with 3 tables.
What I want is a way to generate simple JAVA classes with basic CRUD functions. Any suggestions?

Comment: Does [this related SO topic](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/414583/is-there-a-crud-generator-utility-in-javaany-framework-like-scaffolding-in-rai) help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The de-facto standard is [Hibernate](http://www.hibernate.org/) for object-relational mapping.

The most popular IDEs (NetBeans, Eclipse) have plugins which will generate a configuration and classes based on your existing tables.

Comment: thank you, any suggestions for some free plugins for eclipse??

Comment: Caught me off-guard. I'm more familiar with NetBeans.. :)

Comment: let say NetBeans,I'm free to choose any platform .

Comment: @SamsGood Check the chapter *"Generating Hibernate Mapping Files and Java Classes"* here: https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/web/hibernate-webapp.html